# How to write a code to count number of visits of my site in java (spring mvc)

Tags: java, spring-mvc

We have developed one spring mvc project, it also contains some partner websites. We would like know how many users are visiting my website and redirecting to the partners website.

Please help.

Comment: This is nowhere near enough information.  It is also extremely unclear.  Is the Spring MVC project your website, your partner website, or a different app altogether?

Comment: Our project like advertising application, in that other partners for example Amazon, flipkart, myntra etc. put their shopping offers. Once the user is visited my project, he can see all the partners advertisements once he click on that he will redirects to the their website.

Comment: And you want to see visitor count or how many visitors navigate to partner sites?

Comment: Both. Visitors count and in that which users are redirected to partners sites.